# MDT-Imaged systems default to 1280x1024 when monitor not connected

Tags: windows-7, hp, screen-resolution, mdt-2012, mdt

I have setup an MDT Deployment Share at work that we use to image our Windows 7 workstations. We are using HP Compaq Elite ultra-slim desktops (primarily the 8000, 8200 & 8300 models).

Everything works well, except I have noticed that when the imaged systems boot without a display plugged in, they will default to 1280 x 1024 resolution. This poses a challenge, as I am using a Samsung SyncMaster through a KVM when I image multiple systems. The Samsung doesn't support this resolution, and so often I am unable to see the system's screen to verify that MDT has finished running.

Does anyone know of a way to keep this from happening? FYI, I have set the unattend.xml on my Task Sequences to default to 1024x768, 32-bit, 60Hz. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Don't know how to fix it.  But maybe you could have a startup script or something use a command line to to set the proper screen resolution?  http://superuser.com/questions/89302/any-way-of-changing-windows-7-screen-resolution-via-command-line

Comment: check http://www.sysadminsblog.com/microsoft/set-native-resolution-during-lti-deployment/ or http://scriptimus.wordpress.com/2011/06/01/mdt-2010-configuring-the-native-screen-resolution/

Comment: Thanks @MattBear. Unfortunately according to Scriptimus's blog (which is an amazing resource), my monitors should be defaulting to 1024x768, which is what is confusing to me.

Comment: is this only an issue during the imaging process?

Comment: No, it will continue to happen anytime the system boots up again with no display plugged. Luckily once deployed it is extremely rare for a system to boot up without a monitor plugged in and turned on.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way seems like it be to use a run once or GPO logon/startup script to set the resolution to the desired value, or least a resolution your monitor can display.

(Although, having thought about it for a moment, this isn't a normal problem, in my experience.  Are you missing a monitor or video driver, or perhaps applying the wrong one to your images?)

Comment: We don't apply any display drivers through MDT. After deploying the system Windows 7 seems to grab the correct driver from Microsoft directly (mostly the Samsung display driver). And if a monitor is plugged in upon boot-up it always defaults to the appropriate 1920x1080.

Comment: For a few reasons specific to our environment we don't bind directly through MDT. However, a run-once script of some sort might be a good last resort if I can't figure it out.

Comment: @bispymusic  Doesn't seem to be working too well, at least not to me.  What happens if you *do* deploy a driver with MDT?

Comment: I will give that a try and report back.